# How to calculate value for a expression in a string, then return a new string?

Tags: python

i read data from my config file like this:

```
ip_vlan1 = "10.10.($id+100).5"
ip_vlan2 = "10.11.($id*2+1).6"
v.v...
```

And for each vlan, I want calculate vlan address for it, based on ID and vlan-expression:

```
def calculate_vlan_id(id, vlan_exp):
    ...
    return ip_addr   # string
```

**Example:**

```
def(3, ip_vlan1) --> result: "10.10.103.5"
def(5, ip_vlan2) --> result: "10.11.11.6"
```

Do you have a solution for this?

Thanks in advance, folks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a text templating engine. (Which is safer than using eval based tricks).

Here's an example using [genshi](http://packages.python.org/Genshi/templates.html)

```
from genshi.template import TextTemplate
ip_vlan1 = TextTemplate("10.10.${id+100}.5")
ip_vlan2 = TextTemplate("10.11.${2*id+1}.6")
print( ip_vlan1.generate(id=3) ) # prints 10.10.103.5
print( ip_vlan2.generate(id=5) ) # prints 10.11.11.6
```

If you really need the `calculate_vlan_id` function it would look something like this:

```
def calculate_vlan_id(id,ip_vlan):
  return ip_vlan.generate(id=id)
```

**Edit:**

As requested here's an example using jinja2: This may not be the best way to do this, the jinja2 docs are large and confusing.

```
ip_vlan1 = jinja2.Template('10.10.{{id+100}}.5')
ip_vlan2 = jinja2.Template('10.11.{{2*id+1}}.6')
ip_vlan1.render(id=3)
ip_vlan2.render(id=5)
```

Both these methods are **untested**

Comment: Nice & clear, maybe I will change my config file format to use your solution :D Do you have another option by using Jinja2 template,pls? Thanks alot!

Comment: Hi, i found it:

from jinja2 import Template

ip_vlan1 = Template("10.10.{{id + 100}}.5")

ip_vlan1.render(id=3)

Thanks you!

Answer (score 1):

```
def calculate_vlan_id(id, vlan_exp):
    vlan_exp_list = vlan_exp.split(".") 
    vlan_exp_list[2].replace("$id", id);
    vlan_exp_list[2] = eval(vlan_exp_list[2])

return '.'.join(vlan_exp_list)  # string
```

Comment: Hi, the "$id" is not always in [2] position, it can be any position. And the statement 'vlan_exp_list[2] = eval(vlan_exp_list[2])' error: "SyntaxError: invalid syntax"

Answer (score 1):

IF you are sure that you have only only 'id', then you can do it like this.

```
def replace(id, vlan_exp):
    vlan_exp = vlan_exp.replace('$id',str(id))
    return ".".join(map(str,map(eval,vlan_exp.split('.'))))
```

But that uses eval and using eval can be harmful to your program.